# ActiveAdmin Register Page Batch Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have Custom page "All Posts"
Can i integrate batch action into this custom page for assigning the post to a particular category

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "All Posts" do
  menu :priority => 1#, label: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard")    }
  content do #title: proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") }
      #how can i put here a batch action 
  end
end
```

how can i put here a batch action as it gives errors when i write the batch action for resource code.
should i write the page_action and then customize it using javascript and partials.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why just not to edit needed post?

Comment: @NeverBe i want to assign many posts in bulk to a single category. If single post would have been there i would have assigned it by editing that post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add batch_action by

```
  batch_action :export do |selection|
    keys = Model.find()
    redirect_to admin_path_to_page_with_category_selection_path(post_ids: selection)
  end
```

and selectable column

```
  index download_links: [:xlsx] do
    selectable_column
    .....
  end
```

admin_path_to_page_with_category_selection_path goes to view with category combobox, selected posts and submit button

Comment: it's not resource page it is a custom page. It is **ActiveAdmin.register_page**